# Fixed Background Works in Chrome but Not Firefox?

Tags: css, background, fixed

Am I missing something?

```
body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
   color: #333333;
   font-size: 13px;
   background: white url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center;
}
```

Comment: what your actual want a fixed background image in center or moving background image in center

Comment: @sandeep Fixed, as it is in Chrome

Comment: can you show your example in jsbin.com ?

Comment: @sandeep You can see the website in my profile if you need to. - Sorry, I don't think I can use JSBin because it's a wordpress site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `SearchAndShare.css` there is a `body {background-attachment: inherit;}` rule which, because this sheet is being called later than your main sheet, is overruling the `"fixed"` from your main sheet

removing that rule fixes Firefox, not sure if inherit is a valid call for a background-attachment but even if it is it would mean you would need to be setting `background-attachment: fixed" on the`html`element so the`body` has something to inherit from

**Update:** Yes, if you don't want to mess with the plugin `SearchAndShare.css` file, adding `html {background-attachment: fixed}` to your main sheet also fixes it

Answer (score 1):

When using the shorthand `background` property, the order of the properties should be

1. color
2. image
3. repeat
4. attachment
5. position

Try changing the style as follows (change the `repeat` order and add the `attachment` and see if it makes a difference:

`background: white url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center 0;`

Then remove the `background-attachment:fixed;`

**EDIT:** Apparently mixing keywords and values will cause some browsers to choke.  So `centre 0` might be the issue in FF.

Try `50% 50%` or `center center`

Comment: @Tara. I saw something I hadn't seen before and edited the response above.  Fyi.

Comment: This 'background: white url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center;' works better than 'center center' or '50% 50%' since they place the bg img in the vertical center of the page. However, in firefox, the bg is still not sticking as it does in Chrome. Thanks for the update in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
background: url(under.gif) no-repeat fixed 10% 20%;
```

or

```
width: 780px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 0.8em;
background: url(images/bg.jpg) top left repeat-y;
border: 1px solid #e6930f
```

Hope this helpz...:)

Comment: Sorry @harishtps, but that CSS really doesn't work and I don't know why you felt the need to add an orange border, a different background image, and font size?