# Background-image: fixed works everywhere except Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image, fixed

I'm working on a new website and I want to have a background image fixed, in order to apply parallax in the future.

Here's my html code

```
   <div class="parallax image1"></div>
```

And here's my css

```css
.parallax {
        height: 10em;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .image1 {
        background-image: url("https://d2wq73xazpk036.cloudfront.net/media/27FB7F0C-9885-42A6-9E0C19C35242B5AC/A7BC70EF-2E93-47DA-A355C4B22039324E/thul-6818f8f2-2711-5159-9648-cc23606b037c.jpg");
    }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure sse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="parallax image1"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Everything works well on Chrome 58, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari. The image doesn't show on Firefox. The right height is there, but not the image.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Adding this doesn't work.

```
html {
    background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed Background Works in Chrome but Not Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123304/fixed-background-works-in-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Then create a [mcve] please, so that we can check the actual issue.

Comment: Check [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment#Browser_compatibility), Maybe it should help.

Comment: I've added a snippet with the code I have on my website. It doesn't work on the website, but it does on the snippet. I don't get why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you but i use this for the background of my site:

```
.image1 {
       background: url(yourimage.jpg) background: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/7cDOsrQ.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;}
```

This is for a full size background, but in the html you need to set this`

```
<div class="image1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately it stills doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: i don't know why can you do a fiddle? or a codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmvRaY here's one. It works on the codepen, but not on my website and everything is the same... I don't understand

Comment: ok can you send me the link of your website? if you won't send the link here send that to my email: nicololafasciano@gmail.com